# ExecutorService not executing threads in parallel when using Stream<Future>

Tags: multithreading, java-8

I'm using an `ExecutionService` as follows:

```
    ExecutorService exe = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(parts.size());
    ...
    Stream<Future<String>> futures = parts.stream().map(part -> exe.submit(() -> processPartition(part)));
    ...
    String ret[] = futures.map(t -> {
        try {
            return t.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).toArray(n -> new String[n]);
```

the code inside of `processPartition()` is executing only one at a time.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I spent several hours troubleshooting this and then finally found the answer 2 minutes after posting.

The problem is in this pattern:

```
Stream<Future<String>> futures = [...]
```

By using a stream, each Future is not submitted in until each corresponding `map(t ->` is called.

FIX:

```
List<Future<String>> futures = [...] .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That forces all the threads to get submitted.

Comment: Mind the existence of [`ExecutorService.invokeAll(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-). By the way, `.toArray(n -> new String[n])` can be written as `.toArray(String[]::new)`.